# Why does my Tk application error out with "unknown color name white"?

Tags: ubuntu, tcl, xorg

I  just installed tkdiff on a ubuntu machine and when I try and run the program I get the following error:

```
 actual font: -family {DejaVu Sans Mono} -size -12 -weight normal -slant roman -underline 0 -overstrike 0
Error in startup script: unknown color name "white"
    (processing "-foreground" option)
    invoked from within
"text $w(LeftCB) -height 0 -padx 0 -highlightthickness 0 -wrap none  -foreground white -width 1 -borderwidth 0 -yscrollcommand  [list vscroll-sync "$w(..."
    (procedure "build-client" line 81)
```

Versions:

- Ubuntu 9.04
- tkdiff ??? (Could not find a version number)
- wish 8.5

Does anyone know how I should fix this? I could go into the tkdiff script and change white to a color value but that seems to me like I am fixing the symptom and not solving the real problem. In other words is there something wrong with my tkdiff or wish and the version of ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

Some Google research indicates that there might be a problem with the definition of "rgbpath" in your xorg.conf file (possibly in /etc/X11?).  I'd either ensure that it's value is correct, or possibly remove the line all together.

Jeff

Comment: Thanks for the google help. I tried but was not getting anywhere. I searched all over for an rgbpath setting but could not find it being set anywhere. Maybe if you could send me the links that you found I could try and debug a bit more.

Comment: Do you have a "xorg.conf" file?  If so, the offending setting is likely in it.  I don't have the reference links handy, or I'd post them...

Jeff

Comment: I do but there is no mention of rgbpath. I also grepped around a bit and found no mention of rgbpath.